# Oracle EXPDP from remote client

Tags: expdp, oracle-dump

I am running Oracle `expdp` process from a remote client using the command line. I can see the process starts and there are few progress messages shown in the command prompt window. But, after some time there are no further progress messages. When I checked the log created in the server directory, I could see the `expdp` process is completed and the .dmp file generated. What could be the reason for the command prompt on the client for not receiving the process updates after some time.

Below is `expdp` sample command used.

*expdp Schemas=XXXX directory=exportdir dumpfile =xxxx.dmp logfile=xxxx.log Job_name=xxxx*